# Rails App configurations for AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a rails application that is deployed on `AWS EC2 instance` with `CodePipeline`. I have added the `Build` stage in the pipeline using `AWS CodeBuild` to build test my code.

I have no idea about where to add below `rails command` to execute whenever code auto-deploy using the pipeline.

1. bundle install
2. rake db:migrate, create, assets compile
3. Restart sidekiq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CodeDeploy service as part of your CodePipeline. The pipeline will have two stages, one source stage (taking source from GitHub or CodeCommit etc) and second deploy stage (deploy to EC2 using CodeDeploy).

The CodeDeploy agent will be running on the EC2 instance and will take deployment command from the service. CodeDeploy deployments need an AppSpec file that provides the details of where to copy the source file on the EC2 instance and then run some scripts on the instance ("hooks") where you will do the commands like 'bundle install' or 'restart sidekik' etc.

Instead of me trying to list every step, I found a few resources that may get you started. Try the first tutorial which will help you understand the complete picture (CodeDeploy + CoedPipeline):

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html
- https://dev.to/mknycha/deploying-ruby-app-using-aws-codedeploy-to-ec2-how-to-do-it-with-bundler-49gg
- [How to write appspec.yml for Ruby on Rails on AWS CodeDeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849007/how-to-write-appspec-yml-for-ruby-on-rails-on-aws-codedeploy)